# Make the height and width of a parent div and child textarea equal without hardcoding any height or width

Tags: html, css

The height and width of a parent div containig a child textarea can be made exactly equal with the following CSS: https://jsfiddle.net/BwVQZ/7/

```html
<div>
    <textarea></textarea>
</div>
```

```css
div{
    height: 200px;
    width: 300px;
    background: red;
}
textarea{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
}
```

The problem with the above approach is that I have hardcoded the height and width of the div, which I cannot do for my real use-case.

If I don't hardcode the height and width, then the div gets a slightly bigger height that the textarea: https://jsfiddle.net/731ce2u4/

```html
<div>
    <textarea></textarea>
</div>
```

```css
div{
    background: red;
}
textarea{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
}
```

Does anyone know how to make the height and width of the div and textarea equal, without hardcoding any heights or widths?

Comment: what should ultimately control the height then? The parent's height? The content of the textarea?

Comment: try adding these to the textarea: padding: 0px;
    border: 0px;
    margin: 0px;

Comment: @tacoshy Ultimately, the height of the textarea should control the parent's height.

Comment: @PerdiEstaquel Adjusting the suggested properties does not solve the issue.

Comment: Then you do not need to control the height of the parent at all but keep it at default `height: auto`. However you need to control the height of the textarea which is a commonly asked question.

Answer (score 0):

You want a responsive textarea. Could you try using these rulesets? It's not a perfect solution, but it might work for you.

```css
div {
  max-inline-size: 200px;
  background: red;
  aspect-ratio: 2 / 1;
}

textarea {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  /* Firefox, other Gecko */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* Opera/IE 8+ */
}
```

Answer (score -1):

By default `display: block;` is set.

Use `display: flex;` in parent div container.

```css
div{
    background: red;
    display:flex;
}
textarea{
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
  box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
}
```

```html
<div>
    <textarea></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: what should flexbox fix that does not already happen by default? It does not answer the actual question of auto-sizing the height of the textarea!

Comment: He does not need to give dimensions in pixels for different screen sizes using flexbox. I think by mistake you have misinterpreted the question @tacoshy

Comment: read the comments. * height of the textarea should control the parent's height* which does it already by default. A textarea just gets the default hight and does not resize on its own.

Comment: @tacoshy OP has asked the right question .It seems there might have been a misunderstanding on your part which makes this (SO) community not so welcoming for new users.